# One side farmer carry

Tags: workout, back, hands

Why it is difficult to do one side farmer carry i.e
 I am carrying heavy weight only on one side. I can carry 60 pound each on my both hands in farmer carry. But one sided is hard enough.  Is one side also is any kind of excercise , read somewhere that it puts unnecessary strain on spine. But in everyday life we will carry weight on one side only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One sided or Unilateral Farmer Carries are actually a *fantastic exercise*.

Since *carrying the weight on one side* **causes a lateral flexion (side-bending) and rotational forces**.  To prevent yourself from **literally falling over**, these forces must be *neutralized* -- **by utilizing smaller stabilizing musculature.**

---

In contrast, during a **Standard Farmers Carry** you have weights in both hands, **rather activating key stabilizers the** weights you're carrying simply offset.   ***The anti-rotational / lateral flexion component has been removed***.

---

One thing to note.  **“Unnecessary” stress on the on the spine** (core) is created by movement done in an unnatural, non-functional position.

For example, sit-ups cause dangerously high compression and shearing forces to your spine  -- **about 730 pounds (3300 N)** which well exceed safe levels established by the CDC.

**Larger muscles, with high force production** (global musculature) must compensate by **improperly activating to counteract these forces.***

Done over time, **your literally programming your nervous system to recruit (activate) these muscles at the wrong time** -- such as smaller movements when those large muscles aren't needed.

*Source:* https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unilateral/imbalanced movements are more difficult than bilateral/balanced movements precisely because (and to the extent) of the imbalance, which you must overcome by exerting asymmetric force.

Bilateral/balanced movements such as barbell squats and deadlifts are better for strength development than unilateral/imbalanced movements because the latter, while difficult, significantly reduce the amount of weight that you can handle over a long effective (and safe) range of motion.

Squats, deadlifts, overhead presses, and bench presses stimulate essentially all of the muscles (large and small) that are worth training for most people.